# How to put imageView in extreme left of toolbar?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to put my ImageView Content in extreme left of my toolbar. How can i do so? I have tried the following code:
This is my ToolBar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="4dp"
>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Departure"
    android:src="@drawable/abc"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_image"
    />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"

    ></include>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/listview">

</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my menu.xml

```
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="refresh"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:title="Search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    ></item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_user"
    android:orderInCategory="300"
    android:title="User"

    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"></item>

</menu>
```

And my output is like This is the image is on Right Side of my app Name
[image]

And this is my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="################">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: how are you setting the title of toolbar[app name]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
   <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>
```

It must work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using ToolBar.setTitle() to set app name,so first remove that..

and now change the toolbar xml like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="4dp"
> 

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Departure"
        android:src="@drawable/back2"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_image"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargePopupMenu"
        android:text="your_title"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/page_title"
        />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

when you do this your title will be manually set in the toolbar with the help of textview used and your image will automatically come to left most part of the tool bar

this is not a efficient way, but it works out...

Comment: If it is still not working, then add android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" into imageview present in the toolbar xml...

Comment: Previously the title was set due to this command <android:label="@string/app_name">present in manifest. So i removed it but still my package name is coming in left lemme send u my manifest file too

Comment: Done got it thanx for replying and it help me in other way . And i am posting the answer below

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;           

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);/* Just put this line after setting your Action Bar*/
}
```

Comment: is it not working if you don't write getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnable(false);...?

Comment: Previously i dont know how it used to take default title which was my app name. And when i removed it it used to take my package name. After using this it stopped fetching default name